Unable to install Enrichment app
I am unable to install the enrichment app in my cytoscape 3.10.2.
Undefined error was shown on the screen. I have downloaded the Enrichment map app 3.4.0 version.
Can someone please suggest me which jar file I have to use to install the app.
Thank you in advance

Please [edit] (don't answer in the comments) your question and i) tell us your operating system, ii) what this "app" is, where you got it, and exactly how you tried to install it so we can try to reproduce what you saw.

Do you mean the EnrichmentMap App? https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/enrichmentmap

Please copy-paste the text of the error, or (if that is not possible) a screenshot of the error.

Please provide more information.  EnrichmentMap seems to install fine for me, but I'm on a Linux machine.  What type of OS are you using? What other apps do you have installed? How are you attempting to install it?  All these would be helpful.
